# Problemas al comparar rango de fechas

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

Buenas a todos comunidad, quisiera pedirles si me pudieran ayudar con un problema que tengo sobre una consulta SQL, estoy intentando filtrar un rango de fecha de inicio y de término,
de la siguiente manera:

```
WHERE b.FECHA >=  TO_DATE('09/06/2023', 'DD-MM-YYYY')
AND b.FECHA <=  TO_DATE('16/06/2023', 'DD-MM-YYYY')
```

Sin embargo al hacer esto, por alguna razón el resultado de la query deja fuera de rango la fecha de término, en este caso en vez de traer el '16/06/2023' me retorna las fechas del 15/06/2023" hacia atrás, lo intenté con between para hacer la comparación pero retorna el mismo resultado, no sé qué es lo que puede ser, estoy utilizando sqldeveloper para esto, si alguien pudiera ayudarme, se lo agradecería completamente.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El *problema* debe ser que el campo FECHA tiene información de fecha y hora, mientras que el filtro no, por lo que:

```
where b.fecha between '06/06/2023' and '15/06/2023'
```

Traerá correctamente todos los registros hasta los del 15/06/2023 a las 00:00:00.000, pero no los que están después. (He quitado intencionalmente las conversiones para mayor legibilidad).

Por esa razón, no ves los registros que ocurrieron durante el día del 15/6/2023.  Si lo piensas detenidamente, es lo que estás pidiendo al motor que haga, con tu diseño, en tu consulta.

Hay varias soluciones para este *problema*.

Uno es añadir la última hora del día a la fecha final, por ejemplo:

```
where b.fecha between TO_DATE('09/06/2023', 'DD/MM/YYYY') and TO_DATE('16/06/2023 23:59:59.999', 'DD/MM/YYYY HH:MI:SS.FF3')
```

Esto traerá todos los registros del día, hasta el último milisegundo.

Otra es realizar una conversión para *eliminar* la información de horas y que el motor se fije únicamente en la fecha para filtrar.

```
where trunc(b.fecha) between TO_DATE('09/06/2023', 'DD/MM/YYYY') and TO_DATE('16/06/2023', 'DD/MM/YYYY')
```

De estas, la primera opción suele ser más recomendable, pues hace mejor uso de los índices y es más rápida al no realizar conversiones fila por fila. La segunda es más legible y (en mi opinión) más fácil de mantenr.

En todo caso, si tus tablas tienen volúmenes grandes de información, inspecciona el plan para ambas antes de elegir cual utilizar.

La otra opción es tener una columna que tenga información solamente de la fecha, sin hora. Esta incluso puede ser una columna calculada sobre la que exista un índice para mantener la eficiencia a la hora del filtrado.

Comment: Buenísimo! me ha funcionado, muchas gracias!

Comment: Siempre es mejor usar la función de conversión TO_DATE con la máscara del formato.

Comment: para la fecha-hora final no se requiere la fracción de segundo, pues el tipo DATE no lo tiene y además la función TO_DATE lo descarta:

TO_DATE('16/06/2023 23:59:59', 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS')